# In the United States, can someone take the death penalty for someone else?

Tags: united-states, capital-punishment

Could a person be executed in the place of someone else in United States?

Comment: Not lawfully and not on purpose. Of course, bureaucracies have an infinite capacity to screw up and do something like that by mistake, although it has never happened to the best of my knowledge in the U.S. (at least in peacetime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no legal mechanism by which this could happen.